# sql that can make right count

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Have sqlite table:

```
orderitems
-id
-item_id
-quantity
```

I need to count each item_id
That is not a problem:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT item_id,COUNT(item_id) 
                     FROM sh_orderitems 
                     GROUP by item_id 
                     ORDER by COUNT(item_id) DESC LIMIT 5")->fetchAll();
```

Result is:

```
 0 => 
array (size=4)
  'item_id' => string '38' (length=2)
  0 => string '38' (length=2)
  'COUNT(item_id)' => string '3' (length=1)
  1 => string '3' (length=1)
```

But that is not good solution, 'cause: quantity dos't counted.
Need something like SELECT item_id,COUNT(item_id)*quantity

Comment: What about `SUM( quantity )` ?

Comment: Count row per item_id or sum quantity per item_id??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if yout count rows and order by count..

```
SELECT item_id,SUM(quantity) as `sum_items` 
                     FROM sh_orderitems 
                     GROUP by item_id 
                     ORDER by `sum_items` DESC LIMIT 5
```

or

```
SELECT item_id,sum_items
      FROM (SELECT item_id, SUM(quantity) AS sum_items
                     FROM sh_orderitems 
                     GROUP by item_id)
      ORDER by sum_items DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: So, you need use SUM(quantity).

Comment: finall solution is SELECT item_id,SUM(quantity) FROM sh_orderitems GROUP by item_id